# Changes list_display when choosing different filter options

Tags: python, django

I need to change the displayed columns of django model
For example, I have the following model id - user - type1 - type2 - type3 - type4

And a filter with the following fields - filter1 - filter2 - filter3

How can I display only id - user - type1 fields when filter1 is selected, when filter2 is selected, display only id - user - type2 fields, when filter3 is selected, display only id - user - type3 - type4 fields, is there such a possibility in django?

Comment: Could you be more specific where you are displaying this data? Are you displaying it in django's html?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.